# pywinauto: How to select this dialog? Which spying tool to use? What information do I need on it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, 7zip, pywinauto

How can I write "hello" on the first field of the 7-zip "Add to Archive" dialog?

I managed so far to trigger the 7-zip (windows 64x) "Add to Archive" dialog using this

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application().start(r"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe") #set the app
app.top_window_().Edit.type_keys(r"C:\Users\me\Desktop{ENTER}") 
app.top_window_().SysListView32.Select(r'test.txt') #select files in list
app.top_window_().ToolbarAdd.TypeKeys("{ENTER}") #apply
```

Then I can't select the Add to Archive dialog.

1: This did not work. I guess because it did not find the dialog. If so, why?

```
app.window(title_re="Add to Archive", class_name="#32770").print_control_identifiers()
```

2: This also did not work:

```
app.window(title_re="Add to Archive", class_name="#32770").Edit.type_keys("hello")
```

3: I tried to find all available dialogs on my app using `print(app.windows())`

But it prints this:

```
[<pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.DialogWrapper object at 0x0000000004033D68>, <pywinauto.controls.common_controls.ToolTipsWrapper object at 0x0000000004089128>, <pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.HwndWrapper object at 0x0000000004089208>, <pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.DialogWrapper object at 0x
00000000040893C8>, <pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.DialogWrapper object at 0x0000000004089390>]
```

I don't see any "Add to Archive" windows, why? What are those things (eg. in32_controls.DialogWrapper)?

**Print screen of different spy tools**
spy++ for the dialog
[image]

spy++ on the first control (it says Edit, but au
[image]

inspect.exe for the dialog:
[image]

Comment: But, 7zip can be called from the [command line](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/syntax.htm), why not use that?

Comment: @PeterWood it's good to know, thanks! But I want to fully understand pywinauto (it's a kind of exercise to master it's basic function)

Comment: @PeterWood In localization UI testing, it becomes necessary to proceed through the UI as we need to validate the strings that appear in that window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see `7zFM.exe` spawns another process (it's even another executable!) with this dialog. You need to connect to the new process.

```
app2 = Application().connect(path='7zG.exe', title='Add to Archive')
app2.AddToArchive.print_control_identifiers()
```

[EDIT]

If you open Task Manager (tab "Details" on Win8.1 or Win10) you will see process `7zG.exe`. Another way to see that: in Spy++ when you're looking at the windows hierarchy, right click on the dialog "Add to Archive" and choose "Properties", then switch to tab with ProcessID value (it's shown as a hex number). Compare similar number for the File Manager dialog. There are different ProcessIDs!

In Inspect.exe you can also see property `ProcessId` (== 5304 on your screenshot). Find this value in Task Manager / Details / column `PID`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. `I see 7zFM.exe spawns another process (it's even another executable!) with this dialog.` but where (or how) do you see that? Do you mean you see that on an inspect tool, if so which one? (Do you use the inspect.exe tool or spy++ to see that? Or which one?) I don't see any 7zG.exe in the printscreen above, I'm confuse.

Comment: I added a print screen of the inspect.exe on the dialog (question edited). It doesn't mention 7zG.exe. (I'm even more confuse)

Comment: If you open Task Manager (tab "Details" on Win8.1 or Win10) you will see process `7zG.exe`. Another way to see that: in Spy++ when you're looking at the windows hierarchy, right click on the dialog `"Add to Archive"` and choose "Properties", then switch to tab with ProcessID value (it's shown as a hex number). Compare similar number for the File Manager dialog. There are different ProcessIDs!

Comment: In Inspect.exe you can also see property `ProcessId` (`== 5304` on your screenshot). Find this value in Task Manager / Details / column `PID`.

Comment: thanks a lot! The last point I don't understand is the point number 3 in my question: print(app.windows()) is suppose to show me the windows opened right? So why does it print this?

Comment: The best spying tool seems to be from autohotkey, cf the last print screen ― you can use it in your answer if you want (and delete it in my question).

Comment: `app.windows()` returns actionable wrappers for every window. So you can print texts by `print [w.window_text() for w in app.windows()]`.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as accepted (press grayed check box under voting buttons). Welcome to ask more questions. And thanks for the feedback about spy tools. I have plans to review AHK features in more details. The competition must go on. :)

Comment: just a little correction: `print([w.window_text() for w in app.windows()])` (missing parenthesis)

Comment: Sure, I see you use Py3. It was Py2 snippet.

Comment: I wrote a basic tutorial for basic the users (like me) with my basic understanding of pywinauto (and python). See the answer bellow, so you could see what kind of difficulty we, basic users, encounter. (I would have loved to get these information when I started. You will see that some of them are missing. I don't fully understand, some points related to the print dialog and control).

Answer (score 5):

---

Vasily's already answered the question. I just wanted to gather all the points also mentioned in the comments and in the [latest docs](http://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)). (Answers in *italic*). Don't hesitate to fill up the holes left in this basic tuto (several question remains), or to correct it .

---

**1/ I can't connect to this dialog**

```
app.window(title_re="Add to Archive", class_name="#32770").print_control_identifiers()
```

*Answer: it did not work because it's another process. So it's a kind of new app (app2). So you need to reconnect to it (some apps can launch a new process for each windows they launch).*

*For some app you will also need to specify the "backend", by default it's "win32". If the spy tool (cf bellow) can see the "controls" (name, class, etc. of each field, button...) in the "uia" mode, you should use `Application(backend='uia')`*

*To reconnect you need to do again `app2=Application().connect(path='7zG.exe')` then to select the control*

*It seems that the more you specify stuff to connect the easier it will connect. That's probably why Vasily used the path + the title. I just wanted to show that it also works with only the title ―in this case*

**2/ yes but ow do I know that it's a new process?**

*Answer: You can see that in the spying tool (cf 6/ and the printscreen bellow).*

**3/ I can't select the control (enter text in a field) on that dialog:**

```
app.window(title_re="Add to Archive", class_name="#32770").Edit.type_keys("hello")
```

*Answer: it's normal, you need first to connect to the dialog. First connect to the app2 (cf. above) then do that:*

```
app2.window(title_re="Add to Archive", class_name="#32770").Edit1.type_keys(r"great success!", with_spaces = True)
```

**4/ I tried to find all available dialogs on my app using `print(app.windows())`But it prints this (and other weird stuff):**

```
[<pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.DialogWrapper object at 0x0000000004033D68>, <pywinauto.controls.common_controls.ToolTipsWrapper object at 0x0000000004089128>, <pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.HwndWrapper object at 0x0000000004089208>, <pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.DialogWrapper object at 0x
00000000040893C8>, <pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.DialogWrapper object at 0x0000000004089390>]
```

**I don't see any "Add to Archive" windows, why? What are those things** (eg. in32_controls.DialogWrapper)?

*answer: "it returns actionable wrappers for every window". Each of these strings is the memory location (address) of the object. I don't know how to use them*

*You can get some text using `print ([w.window_text() for w in app.windows()])`  (it print that `['C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\', '', '', 'M', 'Default IME']` No idea what does that means.)*

**5/ If I get all information needed to access these dialog and control do I really need to print these list of dialog or control?**

*I don't know. I don't yet fully understand the need to print the dialog list. But what I understand (maybe) is that this list of control offers way to shorten the code. Eg. it gives things like `AddToArchive`. Instead of writting `app2.window(title_re="Add to Archive").` you could write `app2.AddToArchive.`*

**6/ Spy++ and inspect.exe doesn't even show the process** (plus the second is heavy and buggy)

*Answer: the best spying tool seems to be the one from AutoHotkey (bellow a printscreen of AU3_Spy.exe). It shows the name/class/process and even the control name (and other things) in a tiny window without loading the CPU. And unlike the 2 others spying tool, AutoHotkey gives the right control name*

*Notice also that the control names change from one spying tool to the other. The most accurate seems to be the one from autohotkey (all test worked so far). And it only gives what you need, the other spying tool show a lot of useless stuff exept what you need (such as the process and the real names of the controls)*

[image]

You will find a bunch of spy tool [here](https://github.com/blackrosezy/gui-inspect-tool) Acc explorer complete nicely Ahk (It does the same stuff as spy++, but only better).

(Feel free to use my screenshots)

---

**Extra tips:**

**Is there a way to shorten the code?**

```
.window(title_re="Add to Archive", class_name="#32770")
```

is equivalent to `.AddtoArchive` . So you could also write:

```
app2.AddtoArchive.type_keys(r"great success!", with_spaces = True)
```

Idem for other app like ditto:

```
dittoApp=Application().connect(path='Ditto.exe')
ditto_dialog=ditto.window(best_match='Ditto')
```

Is equivalent to:

```
ditto=Application().connect(path='Ditto.exe')
dittoApp.Ditto
```

**Is there a list of action I can play with?**
You will [here](http://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/controls_overview.html) many action you could perform (on list, button, editing field...).

You can list all available methods of the object using:

```
print(dir(dlg_spec.wrapper_object()))
```

ex:

```
print(dir(ditto.ditto.SysListView321.wrapper_object()))
```

**You need to import the pywinauto modules before using them!**
Modules are the class you need to import (ex: [pywinauto.application module](http://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.application.html))
To use [them](http://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/code.html#main-user-modules) dont forget to import the class! Ex to use one of the method listed in the [findbestmatch module](http://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.findbestmatch.html) you need: `from pywinauto import findbestmatch`

Another example: you need `from pywinauto import keyboard` to use `SendKeys('^a^c')`

Comment: Thanks! Added [feature request 311](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/311) for the docs.